# Unable to retrieve value from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There is such a data structure
(for example, I will give 3 elements, in fact there are several million of them)

```
   '6444': [
    { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
    { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
    { TIME: '142300' },
    { OPEN: '1.14888' },
    { HIGH: '1.14898' },
    { LOW: '1.14881' },
    { CLOSE: '1.14889' },
    { VOL: '835' }
  ],
  '6445': [
    { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
    { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
    { TIME: '142400' },
    { OPEN: '1.14886' },
    { HIGH: '1.14893' },
    { LOW: '1.14874' },
    { CLOSE: '1.14892' },
    { VOL: '889' }
  ],
  '6446': [
    { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
    { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
    { TIME: '142500' },
    { OPEN: '1.14886' },
    { HIGH: '1.14904' },
    { LOW: '1.14886' },
    { CLOSE: '1.14904' },
    { VOL: '772' }
  ]
```

In order to extract at least some value from this table (`TRADING`) and this collection (`EUR/USD`), I use the following code:

```
await client.connect();
const testingData = client.db('Trading').collection('EUR/USD');
const getSomeCurrencyData = await testingData.findOne({'6446': { VOL: '772' }});
```

Questions:

1. Why can't this query retrieve the value from the database?
2. What query can pull at least something specific?
3. Why using query:

   testingData.findOne('6446': [
   { TICKER: 'EURUSD' },
   { DTYYYYMMDD: '20030509' },
   { TIME: '142500' },
   { OPEN: '1.14886' },
   { HIGH: '1.14904' },
   { LOW: '1.14886' },
   { CLOSE: '1.14904' },
   { VOL: '772' }
   ]);

As a result, I get absolutely all the values that exist in the database and not just one specific that I specified?

Comment: `findOne` method always retrieves just _one_ document matching the query filter, and in case there is no matching document returns a `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: But which method can I use to get values from 6446 object?

Comment: Try: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First simply find a document using ID and make sure your DB connection and collection selection has worked. If that is working, then try query like this

   const getSomeCurrencyData = await testingData.findOne({'6446.VOL': '772' });
2. If the above suggestions works, that will do
3. Instead of passing array to find one to match, which does not work, try it like this.

   testingData.findOne({
   "6446.TICKER": 'EURUSD',
   "6446.DTYYYYMMDD": '20030509',
   "6446.TIME": '142500',
   "6446.OPEN": '1.14886',
   "6446.HIGH": '1.14904',
   "6446.LOW": '1.14886',
   "6446.CLOSE": '1.14904',
   "6446.VOL": '772'
   });